# Why does shuffling my validation set in Keras change my model's performance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

**Why I'm confused:**

If I test my model on examples [A, B, C], it will obtain a certain accuracy. If I test the same model on examples [C, B, A], it should obtain the same accuracy. In other words, shuffling the examples shouldn't change my model's accuracy. But that's what seems to be happening below:

**Step-by-step:**

Here is where I train the model:

```
model.fit_generator(batches, batches.nb_sample, nb_epoch=1, verbose=2,
                    validation_data=val_batches,
                    nb_val_samples=val_batches.nb_sample)
```

Here is where I test the model, without shuffling the validation set:

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator()
results = []
for _ in range(3):
    val_batches = gen.flow_from_directory(path+"valid", batch_size=batch_size*2,
                                          target_size=target_size, shuffle=False)
    result = model.evaluate_generator(val_batches, val_batches.nb_sample)
    results.append(result)
```

Here are the results (val_loss, val_acc):

```
[2.8174608421325682, 0.17300000002980231]
[2.8174608421325682, 0.17300000002980231]
[2.8174608421325682, 0.17300000002980231]
```

Notice that the validation accuracies are the same.

Here is where I test the model, with a **shuffled** validation set:

```
results = []
for _ in range(3):
    val_batches = gen.flow_from_directory(path+"valid", batch_size=batch_size*2,
                                          target_size=target_size, shuffle=True)
    result = model.evaluate_generator(val_batches, val_batches.nb_sample)
    results.append(result)
```

Here are the results (val_loss, val_acc):

```
[2.8174608802795409, 0.17299999999999999]
[2.8174608554840086, 0.1730000001192093]
[2.8174608268737793, 0.17300000059604645]
```

Notice that **the validation accuracies are inconsistent**, despite an unchanged validation set and an unchanged model. What's going on?

---

**Note**:

I'm evaluating on the entire validation set each time. [model.evaluate_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#evaluate_generator) returns after evaluating the model on the number of examples equal to `val_batches.nb_sample`, which is the number of examples in the validation set.

Comment: Are you *sure* the validation set is unchanged each time? If you're shuffling and sub-sampling the data each time, that set may be different on each iteration through the testing loop.

Comment: I don't see a problem, you told keras to shuffle the dataset, and that will slightly change the final solutions.

Comment: I'm not subsampling the data. `evaluate_generator` returns after evaluating the model on `val_batches.nb_sample` examples, which is the total number of examples in the validation set. This is too implicit, though. I'll make it more explicit in the walkthrough. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a really interesting problem. The answer is that it's because of that neural networks are using a `float32` format which is not so accurate as `float64` - the fluctuation like this are simply the realisation of an underflow phenomenon.

It case of your loss - you may notice that the differences are occuring after 7th decimal digit of a fractional part - what is exactly the precision of a `float32` format. So - basically - you may assume that all numbers presented in your example are equal in terms of a `float32` representation.

Comment: Assuming this is an underflow problem, why does setting `shuffle=True` cause the inconsistency while setting `shuffle=False` doesn't? Anyway, I think you're right. From Wikipedia: "no more than 9 significant decimal digits can be stored" and I see that for the accuracies, the inconsistencies start at the 10th decimal digit. I'm a little confused about the loss values (first column). Why do the inconsistencies start at the 8th decimal digit there but start at the 10th decimal digit for the accuracies (second column)?

Comment: Significant decimal digits are for the integer part of your number. For fractional part your precision is ~7.25 digits (it's in the same article)