# Fitting a keras model when layers aren't trainable gives inconsistent results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, theano, keras-2

I'm trying to determine the accuracy of my model without training and updating the weights so I've set all of my layers to `trainable = False`.

When I run `fit_generator` on a generator with `shuffle = False`, I get consistent results each time.

When I run `fit_generator` on a generator with `shuffle = True`, the results jump around a bit. Given that the input data is the same, and the model isn't training, I would expect the internal state of the model not to change and the accuracy to be the same on the same dataset regardless of ordering.

However this ordering dependency implies that some sort of state in the model is changing despite `trainable = False`. What's happening inside the model that's causing this?

Comment: Is this reproducible even after setting seed using `numpy.random.seed()`?

Comment: Haven't tried setting the seed, wouldn't that just ensure the same ordering of the input data? My understanding is that ordering shouldn't matter here but I'm clearly missing something

Comment: My suggestion is mostly to test your hypothesis. Neural nets by design are noisy so a reproducible case is always to present.

Comment: That's a good idea, will try that

Comment: Have you tried out my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting phenomenon. It probably arises due to the fact that most of neural networks packages use `float32` precision - which gives you an accuracy up to 5-7 decimal point. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836602/why-does-shuffling-my-validation-set-in-keras-change-my-models-performance/41841375#41841375) you can read a detailed explaination.